# Save file in OS X in a private folder like iOS documents folder

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

Does OS X have a place within the application to save files like how you save files to the documents folders in iOS. I have .plist files to save for my app but I only want to be able to access them form within the app. Don't want do have a folder in the users documents folder or anything.

Primarily an iOS guy so apologies if this is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want here.

To get a directory to store files in an out of the way location, you can use the Application Support directory (`~/Library/Application Support/[APP_NAME]/`).

To get the name of this directory, you pass `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` to [`-URLsForDirectory:inDomains:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLsForDirectory:inDomains:) (see: [Managing Files and Directories](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html)).

---

To prevent the user from reading a file, you can encrypt it  (see: [Encrypting and Hashing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html)).

Comment: Yeah the question was worded poorly. This is just what I was looking for. A standard place to keep files out of the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
-(void) setupApp {
    NSString * myAppPath = [[Configurations createApplicationDirectoryWithPathComponent:MY_APP_DIR_NAME] path];
   self.plistPath = [myAppPath stringByAppendingString:CONFIG_FILE_NAME];
   [self createNewConfigFileWithDictionary:yourDictionary];
}

-(void) createNewConfigFileWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
    @try {
        NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.plistPath]) {
                [dictionary writeToFile:self.plistPath atomically:YES];
        }
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"[MyClass createNewConfigFileWithDictionary] Problem:%@ Description: %@", [exception name],[exception reason]);
    } @finally {}
}

+ (NSURL*) createApplicationDirectoryWithPathComponent:(NSString*)path {
    NSFileManager*fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL*    dirPath = nil;
    // Find the application support directory in the home directory.
    NSArray* appSupportDir = [fm URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    if ([appSupportDir count] > 0) {
        // Append the bundle ID to the URL for the
        // Application Support directory
        dirPath = [[appSupportDir objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:path];
        // If the directory does not exist, this method creates it.
        // This method is only available in macOS 10.7 and iOS 5.0 or later.
        NSError*    theError = nil;
        if (![fm createDirectoryAtURL:dirPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&theError]) {
            @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"CreateApplicationDirectoryWithPathComponentException"
                                           reason:theError.localizedDescription
                                         userInfo:nil];
            return nil;
        }
    }
    return dirPath;
}
```

[Source:](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html)